# Create PDF from Template

Tags: c#, html, templates, pdf

I need to create a PDF File with c#. It have to be that I need a template (eg. Editable PDF or HTML Template).
In this template I have to insert text and Picutures.

I have no ideas how to do this. Could someone say me a technique I could use do this?

Comment: I've removed your request for libraries since that's off-topic.

Comment: try itextsharp to generate pdf from html template

Comment: @John: and so it's now a request for a full tutorial, which is similarly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) -- in the same sentence, no less: "4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic ..."

Comment: @usr2564301 That's true.

Comment: i dont want a tutorial. just an idea -.-

Comment: Why do you need to create a PDF? Why not just use HTML forms, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PdfSharp plugin via NuGet. Just create html template file, read it as string, replace what you need, and pass full html to function bellow.

```
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp;

    public static bool PdfSharpConvert(String html, string SaveTo)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4))
            {
                pdf.Save(SaveTo);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can you deal with page related things like page breaks with an approach like this?

Comment: Sorry dont know, in my experience better to write pdf in code not from html. Like other answer - choosen that path. Static template but at least im in control of every aspect. This example which i provided have it's shortcomings, like page breaks. So i guess this answer is good until you have 1 page.

Comment: @SteffenBauer you can add page breaks to HTML via CSS and most of the time the PDF generator will honour it. I only know because I had the same issue.